# QEMU emulator for Radxa Rock 5B

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-source, qemu

I am working on this Radxa Rock 5B board:
https://wiki.radxa.com/Rock5/hardware/5b

The main system CPU is a Quad-core ARM Cortex-A76 MPCore processor and quad-core ARM Cortex-A55 MPCore processor.

I have built the Android source image for the Rock 5B board using below commands:

```
repo init -u https://github.com/radxa/manifests.git -b Android12_RK3588_Radxa_rk12 -m rockchip-s-release.xml

repo sync
source build/envsetup.sh
lunch RadxaRock5B-userdebug
// run the build script
```

The above builds successfully `gpt.img`. It is flashed on Rock 5B hardware and runs successfully.

But I want to run `gpt.img` on some kind of emulator. How do I achieve this ????

What I have tried or have concerns:-

1. Running android `emulator` fails in the project root.
2. As far as I know `qemu` takes `-cpu` option for the core. But on the Rock 5B board there are 2 different ypes of cores. How do I specify this on QEMU ??

Comment: In general you can't run a bare metal image intended for one kind of Arm machine on a different Arm machine. This is the same for emulation: unless whatever emulator you are using models the Radxa Rock 5B specifically, the image will not boot on it. QEMU doesn't model that board.

Comment: @PeterMaydell. OK Thanks. So what are the other alternatives that I have other than QEMU ??? Or what is the **closest** that I can get for emulating RadXa Rock 5B board ???